Group generated by "adjacent" permutations of graph
Let $G=(V,E)$ be any graph, i.e. $E$ is simply a binary relation over $V$. We say a permutation $\sigma\in \text{Bij}(V)$ of the vertices of $G$ is adjacent if, for all $v\in V$, $(v,\sigma(v))\in E$. Then the adjacency group of $G$, $A(G)$, is defined as the subgroup of $\text{Bij}(V)$ generated by the adjacent permutations of $G$.
Here are some examples.
$A(C_n^d)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $C_n^d$ is the cyclic, directed, looped, graph of order $n$ (looped meaning that the identity permutation is adjacent).
If $G$ is finite, undirected, connected and looped, then $A(G)=\text{Bij}(V)$.
$A(C_4)\cong D_8$ where $C_4$ is the simple cyclic graph of order 4. $A(C_n)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for odd $n$ and, for even $n$, $A(C_n)$ blows up.
If $G$ and $H$ are looped then $A(G\sqcup H)=A(G)\times A(H)$. As a consequence, every finitely generated abelian group is the adjacency group of some graph.
My question is simple: is every (finite?) group the adjacency group of some graph?

For clarification, looped means there is a loop attached to every vertex, which you need to allow for bijections that map some of the vertices to themselves?

Yes. I'll add that.

No, you can't realize the quaternion group $Q$ of order 8 in this way.
Suppose that $Q$ acts on a graph $X=(V,E)$ in an adjacent and faithful way, and let us prove that the "adjacent group" of this graph contains an element of order 8. So there is a generating subset $S$ of $Q$ such that every element of $S$ is adjacent on $X$.
Let $u,v$ be two non-commuting elements of $S$ (so $u$, $v$ have order 4 and generate $Q$), and define $z=[u,v]$ (the generator of the center of $Q$, of order $2$). Let $x$ be a vertex not fixed by $z$, and let $Y$ be the $Q$-orbit of $x$. So $Y$ has cardinal 8 (otherwise $x$ would be fixed by $z$, since every proper subgroup of $Q$ contains $z$).
We have $Q=\{1,u,v,w,z,-u,-v,-w\}$, where $w=uv$, $-u=zu$ (etc.). So $Y=\{x,ux,zx,-ux,vx,wx,-vx,-wx\}$.
Define a permutation $s$ of $V$ as follows: $sy=uy$ for each $y\notin Y$, $s$ is defined on $Y$ as the following 8-cycle:
$$x\stackrel{u}\mapsto ux\stackrel{v}\mapsto-wx\stackrel{u}\mapsto vx\stackrel{v}\mapsto zx\stackrel{u}\mapsto -ux\stackrel{v}\mapsto wx\stackrel{u}\mapsto -vx\stackrel{v}\mapsto x$$
(i.e. we alternatively apply $u$ and $v$ to $x$).
So $s$ is an adjacent permutation of order 8, as required, and hence the subgroup generated by adjacent permutations is strictly larger than $Q$.

I don't think you can assume in the first place that $Q$ acts adjacently on $X$ if by "adjacent" you mean that $(v,gv)\in E$ for all $v\in V$ and $g\in Q$. You can only assume that $u$ and $v$ "act" in such a way on $X$.

Unimportantly, the order of $s$ is only at least $8$.

@aleph2 1) yes, I only assumed that $u$, $v$ act adjacently (I abused language saying that $G$ acts adjacently, meaning that elements in the generating subset are indeed adjacent — the second paragraph of the post is quite clear on this). 2) No, $s$ definitely has order 8. Indeed it is a 8-cycle on $Y$, and acts by $u$ (which has order 4) outside $Y$.

True! Thank you.
